# I want to open a pop up on my main screen when user click on notification message

Tags: android, android-layout

My application is sending a notification.I want to implement when a user check notification and click on the notification I want to open a pop up on my application main screen.It is some thing like that my main screen stay as it is but a pop up will open in front 
of it.
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a `Broadcast a intent` and a `Intent Receiver`

Below is my `create Notification` code.
You will need to broadcast an intent when user clicks on notification icon.

```
    // create NotificationManager..
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, null,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    // create intent that will be broadcast.
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(this, BReceiver.class.getName());    
    i.setAction("Test");

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
            i, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, null, null, contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Below is my `BroadCast Receiver`

```
public class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("Test", "########## intent action "+ intent.getAction());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

The toast will be displayed when you click on the notification icon. It doesnot matter on which screen you are, the toast will be displayed whenever user click notification icon.

Comment: I implemented this code but I couldnt get the toast msg. Should I do some thing else with this code??? Kindly briefly describe if some entries or other thing I have to do along with this code.

Comment: @malikM : Did u register BReceiver.java as a receiver in AndroidManifest.xml.  It worked at my side.

Comment: @malikM : You need to add -------------------------------------------------------------------- <receiver android:name=".BReceiver"></receiver>  inside <application> tag

Comment: HI ishank I achieved the functionality of pop up but now its not opening my application when I click on notification it should broad cast the intent and start my application as well.I need both functionality at same time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @malikM : Since you need both functionality (1. start your application. and 2. show popup) then you you should call startActivity(intent(specifying your application's main activity)) from the BReceiver.onReceive() and then show the popup.

Answer (score 1):

put this

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in meanifeast for your target activity

Answer (score 0):

Try using Alert Builder, 
Here is a snippet of code fir it,

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
            setCancelable(false).
            setTitle("Title for popup").
            setMessage("Show Message here").
            setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }).create().show();
```

Comment: no I am not asking about opening a pop up. Let me give you example my application is running and Home Screen is open. My application send a notification on some instant. When I see notification and click on notification It will come back to my home screen when It come back to home screen I want to open a pop up at that time.Hope some scenario is clear to you.

Comment: Actually I am notifying the user that your phone is turn into silent mode when he click on notification he will navigate to my app home screen with a pop up where I ll give option keep you phone silent or turn to normal mode. This is the scenario for which I want to open pop up on user click to notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you're basically asking about HOW to open the dialog (which I'm assuming you've created as an activity) upon clicking the notification, then check out the Notification docs regarding the [addAction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#addAction%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method in the Notification.Builder class. It allows you to launch any intent you specify upon clicking the notification.